# Need to convert a value from a textbox to an Integer

Tags: powershell

I need help in the following;

This is the cmd-let

```
Set-Datastore [-Datastore] <Datastore[]> [[-Name] <String>] [-CongestionThresholdMillisecond <Int32>]
```

I have a textbox which will be used with '-CongestionThresholdMillisecond' parameter. I have tired different ways but either get cannot convert string to int or value is less than 5 (not permitted).

```
$textBox417.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size (80,30)
$textBox417.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (100,140)
$int = $textBox417.Value.ToString() 
$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size (110,30)
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (50,180)
$button.add_click({Set-Datastore -Name $label438.Text -CongestionThresholdMillisecond $int})
```

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're referring to a property that doesn't exist. Try changing the Value property to the Text property

```
$int = $textBox417.Text
```

Comment: What I first tried, it seems to pass 0.                                           Set-Datastore : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'CongestionThresholdMillisecond'. The 0 argument is less than the minimum allowed 
range of 5. Supply an argument that is greater than 5 and then try the command again.

Comment: Print $int before you pass it to the command, do you get the same value as in the textbox?

Comment: Get '0' as above. Even trying '$int = $textBox417.value -as [int]' still get 0.

Comment: You get 0 because the default value of int is 0 (e.g [int]''). You still didn't answer my question. What written in that text box? If the value of CongestionThresholdMillisecond  requires a certain length of digits then you must validate that before calling the cmdlet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm entering any value between 5 and 100, anything less than 5 isn't in the required range.

Comment: Yes it displays the same error message at the top of this thread

Comment: And when you cast it ti an int? Does it also happens when you invoke the command directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the right number from the textbox it's easy to change a string to an int.

```
$string = '123'
$string.gettype()
([int]$string).gettype()
```

So why can't you do

```
...
$button.add_click({Set-Datastore -Name $label438.Text -CongestionThresholdMillisecond ([int]$int)})
```